# Recalling the date that was picked by the user rather than current date

Tags: jquery

I have a date picker as below which is not bringing back the date that was picked by the user, instead it is bringing back the latest month and the year. How can i change the function so that it always brings back the date that was saved in the database, or the date that selected by the user on the input field rather than the original date.[This is what the function is returning as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfQ5I.jpg)

```js
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     showOn: 'both',
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     showButtonPanel: true,
     constrainInput: false,
     buttonImage: "../jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/images/calendarNew.gif",
     buttonText:"Please select a date",
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     closeText: 'Clear', // Text to show for "close" button
     onClose: function () {
      var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
      // If "Clear" gets clicked, then really clear it
      if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
       $(this).val('');
         }}});
  
   });
  
 
  
    </script>
```

```css
 <style>
         img.ui-Datepicker-trigger {
          position: relative;
          left: -25px;
          top: 2px;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input name="Date" id="Date"  class ="datepicker" value="#dDate#" onChange="setFormChanged(this);"/>&nbsp;<font color="Teal" size="-2">&nbsp;{dd/mm/yyyy} #dOccDate# </font>
```

Comment: You specify a `dateFormat` with dashes `dd-mm-yy` but your value contains slashes `23/06/2015`. Adjust one or the other.

Comment: Jasen you are right i should be consistent with the format. The actual value was being date formatted with something else, however I still cannot  figure out why the recall is showing the current date versus the picked date

Comment: When I tried it with the value matching the format it worked as you want it. Look at the rendered html to see the actual value.

Comment: Jasen that did it, it was the validation mismatch that was causing issues. Thank you for your help.